# Excel COUNTIFS between two times

Tags: excel, countif

I have a list of call logs in Excel and I want to determine the number of concurrent calls at any one time. I have attempted to solve this issue using the COUNTIFS function but I am not getting the desired result.
The structure of my table is as shown below:

```
  |A                   |B       |C                  |D          |E
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1|Start Time          |Duration|End Time           |Time       |Number Of Concurrent Calls
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2|03/09/2018 07:45:08 |00:00:06|03/09/2018 07:45:14|   07:45:08|0
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3|03/09/2018 08:19:51 |00:01:18|03/09/2018 08:21:09|   07:45:09|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4|03/09/2018 08:21:25 |00:04:40|03/09/2018 08:26:05|   07:45:10|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5|03/09/2018 08:26:51 |00:00:48|03/09/2018 08:27:39|   07:45:11|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 6|03/09/2018 08:45:52 |00:00:52|03/09/2018 08:46:44|   07:45:12|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 7|03/09/2018 08:47:50 |00:00:45|03/09/2018 08:48:35|   07:45:13|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 8|03/09/2018 08:55:31 |00:00:56|03/09/2018 08:56:27|   07:45:14|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 9|03/09/2018 08:59:41 |00:03:47|03/09/2018 09:03:28|   07:45:15|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10|03/09/2018 09:04:41 |00:03:05|03/09/2018 09:07:46|   07:45:16|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The time column has values for every time between the first value in the "Start Time" column and the last value in the "End Time" column. The last column shows the number of concurrent calls at the time in the "Time" column. I am using the COUNTIFS formula for the "Number Of Concurrent Calls" column but it is showing the values shown in the table.
This is the formula I'm using for cell E2:
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$1034,">="&D2,$C$2:$C$1034,"<="&D2)
I am counting the number times the value in D2 appears between values in column A and column C, however all the cells in column E have a value of 0 after running the formula.

Can someone assist me in debugging the formula or point me to another tool that can help get the values for column E. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any concurrent calls in your sample...

Comment: Yes I am using the formula shown in E2 to get the concurrent calls but it is giving a wrong result

Comment: I mean I looked at the start and end times (columns `A` and `C`) in your sample and none of the calls are concurrent, so I would expect the count of concurrent calls to be `0`, which it is....

Comment: There should be 1 concurrent call from E2 to E8 as the first call runs from 07:45:08 to 07:45:14. However, my formula only shows 0 for all cells in column E.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here as I see no calls for which the start time (in column `A`) is before the end time of the previous call (in column `C`), which is how I would test for concurrent calls.

Comment: What I am looking for is the total number of calls that are going on at a particular time, so for the range E2:E8 that would be 1.

Comment: Do you want to do this just for one day or for several days? If you were to continue your column D & E for (say) 10 hours you would get 36000 data points - is that what you really want?

Comment: Yes I have no problem with that I am running daily reports, Excel can easily handle 36000 data points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK there are two things going wrong

(1) You are comparing a time with a date-time (as hinted at by @pnuts)

(2) Your < and > need to be swapped.

So suppose you have the date that you want to report on in (say) H2.

Then you need to add the date (dates are whole numbers) to the time (times are fractions of a whole number) giving you a formula like

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,"<="&$H$2+D2,$C$2:$C$10,">="&$H$2+D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I am getting the result I required. I can build from this.